# django pagination with multiple lists

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-endless-pagination

I am using Django pagination.There are 2 scenarios

1. When user lands on this page the result set returns pre-filtered results so I don't necessarily need to paginate the results.
2. When user turns off filters,I need to show all results( this is when I need to paginate,10000 s of records) Those records come to view in form of different lists
   And I send the result as a zipped format.

I am not able to paginate through more than 1 list/result set.

Comment: You have to pass different lists to the Paginator - default in default case, and "unfiltered" in another.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Can you please give an example? Thanks

Comment: is this result a django queryset or just a list of django objects?

Comment: result is list of values from different tables

Comment: check my answer, are you able to combine different queryset to a single one as a list?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to give `Paginator` a list of objects
The number of items you’d like to have on each page, and it gives you methods for accessing the items for each page: [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/)

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage

# 1st OPTION: in case you have multiple queryset 
from itertools import chain
queryset1 = Queryset.objects.all()
queryset2 = Queryset.objects.all()
YourObjectList = sorted(chain(queryset1,queryset2),reversed=True)
# 2nd Option: with Django union queryset
YourObjectList = queryset1.union(queryset2)

object_list = YourObjectList # Queryset of List of Objects
number_items = 10  # The number of items you’d like to have on each page

page = request.GET.get("page",1)
# Get the page parameter i.e localhost:8080?page=1
paginator = Paginator(object_list,number_items)
try:
    object_list = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    object_list = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    object_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

# add the [object_list] to context for [template]
```

in the template, you can loop through it to display all the objects

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {{obj}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

**BONUS**: How you can display Paginator almost like [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=pagination+bootstrap&client=ubuntu&hs=3O8&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyzaCCnvTaAhUE0lMKHR2RDgAQ_AUICigB#imgrc=aP-VIlLCu_sV5M:)

```
{% if object_list.has_other_pages %}
    <div class="pagination">
        {% if object_list.has_previous %}
                <a href="?&page={{object_list.previous_page_number}}">Previous</a> -
        {% endif %}
                Page {{object_list.number}} / {{object_list.paginator.num_pages}}

        {% if object_list.has_next %}
                - <a href="?page={{object_list.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks Lemayzeur. Do I repeat this for each list and add all to the context ?

Comment: In the templates, if you are gonna use a single list of items, you can merge all the lists that you have in backend into a single one, and send it through context.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll try and get back. Thanks

Comment: Just updated my answer, with 2 different ways about how to merge two or more queryset