# How to apply pagination to a filtered queryset in Django

Tags: django, pagination

I'm currently stuck with applying pagination to my Django view codes. Basically, paginate_by seems automatically to work with `queryset` attribute in CBV. But, in my case, I'm not just using `queryset` attribute. I'm using filtered `queryset` on my own. How can I apply pagination to my codes?

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    model = Store
    template_name = 'boutique/search.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

          search_text = request.GET.get('search_text')
          sorter = request.GET.get('sorter')

          if not sorter:
              sorter = 'popularity'

          if search_text:
              search_stores = Store.objects.filter(Q(businessName__icontains=search_text) | Q(mKey__icontains=search_text))
              if sorter == 'businessName':
                  search_stores = search_stores.order_by(sorter)
              else:
                  search_stores = search_stores.order_by(sorter).reverse()
          else:
              search_stores = ''

          for store in search_stores:
              store.mKey = store.mKey.split(' ')

          return render(request, self.template_name, {
              'search_stores': search_stores,
              'search_text': search_text,
              'sorter': sorter,
          })
```

**-------------------------UPDATE2-------------------------**

I'm stuck with getting inputs from HTML input tags. Currently, I just put `self.kwargs()`, but I don't know what I should use instead of them.

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    model = Store
    template_name = 'boutique/search.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['search_text'] = self.kwargs['search_text']
        context['sorter'] = self.kwargs['sorter']
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):

        search_text = self.kwargs['search_text']
        sorter = self.kwargs['sorter']

        if not sorter:
            sorter = 'popularity'

        if search_text:
            search_stores = Store.objects.filter(Q(businessName__icontains=search_text) | Q(mKey__icontains=search_text))
            if sorter == 'businessName':
                search_stores = search_stores.order_by(sorter)
            else:
                search_stores = search_stores.order_by(sorter).reverse()
        else:
            search_stores = ''

        for store in search_stores:
            store.mKey = store.mKey.split(' ')

        return search_stores
```

Comment: I just came to respond to a similar question [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50220476/5644965)

Comment: @Lemayzeur that one seems based on FBV

Comment: It also does the trick, as @will said, place your code in `get()` method

Comment: @Jay I think you're original question has changed. Perhaps create a new question focussed on how to access html inputs in a view. Your original question is about how to apply pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've overridden the `get` method of the `ListView` and have not called up the `super` chain. As a result, the pagination bits and bob that are implemented in the parent `ListView.get()` are not getting called.

Rather place your filtering actions in the `get_queryset()` or `get_context()` methods (both will have access to `self.request`) or make sure to call the parent `get()` in your `get()`.

---

Look at the source code. `ListView` inherits `BaseListView` which implements the pagination stuff.

```
class BaseListView(MultipleObjectMixin, View):
    """
    A base view for displaying a list of objects.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()

        if not allow_empty:
            # When pagination is enabled and object_list is a queryset,
            # it's better to do a cheap query than to load the unpaginated
            # queryset in memory.
            if self.get_paginate_by(self.object_list) is not None and hasattr(self.object_list, 'exists'):
                is_empty = not self.object_list.exists()
            else:
                is_empty = len(self.object_list) == 0
            if is_empty:
                raise Http404(_("Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.") % {
                    'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,
                })
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

But your code never calls `BaseListView.get()` so no pagination is ever done.

More importantly, you need to tell your CBV what to paginate on. See that first line? That is why you need a `get_queryset` method which literally returns the queryset that is going to be used for pagination.

Now your context variables get implemented in `get_context_data` which is provided by your parent hierarchy. Here you build up the context data that will be used in your templates.

Comment: Since I'm new to Django, Do you mind explaining that more in detail with some brief example?

Comment: @Jay since you ask for one based on CBS, [this blog](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html) can be useful

Comment: @Will I think I'm getting a bit closer, but I'm stuck with getting inputs from HTML input tags, since I need to filter the queryset with the inputted values. I put my codes by updating the original post, can you take a look?

Comment: Would need to see your template. Basically, if your inputs are wrapped in a form then you'll get them in self.request.POST. Otherwise you'll need a bit of JS to provide your input values as query params and then you'll get them in self.request.GET. self.kwargs will give you your named URL params specified in your url routes

Comment: The actual pagination is done in `get_context_data()` (which calls `paginate_queryset()`), so the key is to call `context = self.get_context_data()` in the OP's `get()`. See [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/views/generic/list.py#L118).

Answer (score 3):

I strongly advocate for using this phantasmic library for filtering: https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter

for the purpose of filtering you define FilterSet with specifying model and allowed fields for filtering

```
import django_filters


class SpotFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Spot
        fields = [
            'is_certificated',
            'name',
            'location',
            'spot_type',
            'tags',
        ]
```

then in the view you provide `filterset_class` and override `BaseFilterView`

```
from django_filters.views import BaseFilterView


class BaseSpotListView(BaseFilterView, ListView):
    template_name = 'www/spot_list.html'
    model = Spot
    paginate_by = 6
    context_object_name = 'spots'
    filterset_class = SpotFilterSet
```

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for. Using django-filter and paginating this way worked wonderfully for me. I may have missed it, but the docs don't make this very clear.